# Code is stuck in gst_app_sink_pull_sample gStreamer

Tags: c++, gstreamer, rtsp

I want to write all frames in a file from the stream using gStreamer from an rtsp source. I tried the following code but it does not pass the gst_app_sink_pull_sample and it gets stuck.

```
pipeline = gst_parse_launch("playbin uri=rtsp://IP/ ! jpegenc ! appsink name = sink", NULL);
bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
sink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "sink");
appsink = (GstAppSink*)sink; //tried appsink = GST_APP_SINK(sink); also
sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appsink);
GstBuffer* buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
GstMapInfo map;
gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);
Mat frame(Size(320, 240), CV_8UC3, (char*)map.data, Mat::AUTO_STEP);  //if its a 320x240 size image
imwrite("XYZ.jpg", frame);
```

Comment: what is the meaning of "I cannot"? Are there compiler errors? Please include them in the quesiton

Comment: No error but the stream stops and any print after this line is not printed

Comment: please explain in the question what the code should do and what it does instead

Comment: I edited it, hope it's clear now